# How to convert java string to Code page 857

Tags: java

I have a requirement to convert java string to Code Page 857 . I am sending this string to another system which reads the string byte by byte. If this string contains any some Turkish character it will consume 2 bytes. So the client (external system owner) want us to convert (set the standard) the string to code page 857 (standard used to write Turkish chars under DOS operating system)

Please let me know if any one can help me on this
Thanks in advance
Shaji

Comment: It's not clear at all what specifically it is that you want. Do you have string in random charset? Or is it already has Cp857 and you just need to signal that fact? Where does this string come from and where the consumer is?

Comment: Hi Prokhorov, Thanks for your response. Basically I am retrieving some string from a database and send to external system which reads the string byte by byte. In case any Turkish character contains inside the string it will occupy 2 bytes rather 1 byte. All other characters occupies only 1 byte. This leads to error at external system. So they are asking me to set the code page to cp857 (Turkish char) then send the string to them. Hope I answered your question.

Answer (score 3):

Internally, Java represents all Strings as UTF-16. Therefore, a String object itself cannot be converted to a  specific code page.

However, you can get a byte array which encodes the String using a specific character set:

```
String.getBytes(Charset charset)
```

In your case, you should use:

```
byte[] stringAsByteArray=myString.getBytes(Charset.forName("Cp857"));
```

According to [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/intl/encoding.doc.html), Cp857 should be supported by Java, but you should check this with

```
Charset.isSupported("Cp857");
```

Comment: Thanks Markus for your support.